# Python - How to find out length of elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

list = ['abcd', '1.3', 'a', 'abcdef', '12345']

I need a command that gives me the elements that have length greater than 3 (abdc, abdcef, 12345). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`[item for item in list if len(item) > 3]`

If you want to read up more about this, it's called a "[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)".

Answer (score 1):

I would use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> list = ['abcd', '1.3', 'a', 'abcdef', '12345']
>>> [e for e in list if len(str(e)) > 3]
['abcd', 'abcdef', '12345']
>>>
```